# pyplot.gca() in uncalled function produces another subplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a function in my code that takes an Axes-instance to plot on. I want to set the default to be the current axis. This leads to the followig code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plotfunc(ax=plt.gca()):
    # Here I would usually plot some functions on ax
    return True

plt.figure()
plt.show()
```

What I would expect from this script is one blank figure showing up. But what I get is one figure and another empty subplot, although I din't even call plotfunc. The additional subplot doesn't appear when I delete the "=plt.cga()" part in the code. Is there a way to set pltgca() as the standard axis for plotfunc without getting another subplot?

I'm using python 3.6 under Ubuntu 18.04.1.

Comment: Your question is a special case of the ["Least astonishment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) canonical, but I figured it's significantly different at its core so I decided to add an answer. It's worth reading the question and top answers there, because it helps you understand how default keyword arguments work in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python default keyword arguments to a function are set during *definition* of the function (as opposed to *call* time). So what happens when you run that script is:

1. the import is executed
2. `plotfunc` is defined -> `plt.gca()` is executed and the return value is bound to the default value of `ax`
3. `plt.figure()` is executed
4. `plt.show()` is executed

Even though the function is never called, the default keyword argument is set and a corresponding `Axes` (and figure) is created. Then `plt.figure()` explicitly creates a new figure, the second one you see.

You should set a sentinel value to `ax`, as in `ax=None`, then override `if ax is None: ax = plt.gca()` inside the function which only happens on a function call.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to allow for an axes to be supplied to a function and fall back to the "current axes" if none is given would be

```
def plotfunc(ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    # plot something to ax
    ax.plot(...)
```